# Pgfplots ignoring domain

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to use pgfplots to plot `-3ln(x-2)`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{mystyle2/.style={
        width=12cm,
        height=12cm,
        xmin=0,xmax=15,
        ymin=-10,ymax=10}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[mystyle2,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel={$g(x) = -3ln(x-2)$}
    ]
    \addplot[
    domain=2:15,
    y domain=-10:30
    ]
     {(-3)*ln(x-2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to display the function up until y=10, however it seems to cut off at y=2. Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: try changing your `x` domain from `2:15` to something like `2.2:15`.

Comment: @WillieWong That did it (although I used 2.02). I guess it tries to calculate x=2 and craps out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up taking Willie Wong's advice and used a domain of `2.02:15`. It seems that since `(-3)ln(x-2)` is undefined for `x=2` it doesn't try a different point that would display the graph appropriately.

Comment: I don't see why you think it would (try a different point). I mean, it evaluates the function where you've told it to, and it gets a NaN for x=2, so it *does* display the graph appropriately according to your specifications. By the way, you're also affected by the fact that `pgfplots` uses just 25 sample points by default, so the first point is calculated for x = 2, the next one for 2.54, and so on. A larger number of samples (e.g. `samples=400`) would also give you what you're after.